# In a list of names i want only the repeated names to display, in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of people (say column A) with their corresponding Revenue (say in column B) in google spreadsheet. It would be great if someone can help me out in finding a formula to filter only the names which are repeated more than 2 times with their corresponding revenues.

This is the link for google spreadsheet from which my question can be clearly understood. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wc39iKiKEWgJpty83rfFq9HG2Fm-1CRE8leD37Vf4C0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

`=ArrayFormula(FILTER(A3:B,countif(A3:A,A3:A)>2))`

number 2 and `>` is the number of times and dependency (<, >, =, >=, <=),  may be changed to your needs.

---

will work without ArrayFormula part:

`=FILTER(A3:B,countif(A3:A,A3:A)>2)`

This is because [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) acts like array itself.

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h977WxSWC0ORCzjWd5KCYSpEg4-FckjQlABlfus2OyI/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: That works great. Thank you. But if I add one more condition to filter formula (say i have dates in the 3rd column and have to filter within some date range) it seems to be not working properly. 
I am having a hard time understanding why it's not working if i add one more condition.

Comment: What is your final formula?

Comment: This is how it looks like: =COUNTUNIQUE(Filter('Shifts import'!$G$3:$G,Countif('Shifts import'!$G$3:$G,'Shifts import'!$G$3:$G)>2,'Shifts import'!$A$3:$A<=AE3)). Basically what is happening here is I am taking the list of people who are repeated more than 2 times in the list with a condition which has dates (which is: 'Shifts import'!$A$3:$A<=AE3) and counting those unique names.

Comment: Your formula looks right, but if filter desn't return any result, the fotmula will give an error. Try my sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h977WxSWC0ORCzjWd5KCYSpEg4-FckjQlABlfus2OyI/edit?usp=sharing